# OpenAPI: Can you use sub-components inside examples?

Tags: swagger, openapi

OpenAPI version: 3.0.1.

I'm working on the examples-section of an OpenAPI-specification.

I am familiar with components, and I know that I can define examples-components that are to be used at root level.
For instance:

```
...
  examples:
    Students:
      $ref: '#/components/examples/students'
```

In my case, however, I am working with only one endpoint that may give huge and varying content in the response.
Therefore I'm working with several different examples, and creating a component for one full example is of no use to me.

On the other hand, I'm reusing sub-parts in several examples, and I would like to create components based on these sub-parts.

Something like this simplified example, where I have a list of students with the same teacher and postal address:

```
...
  examples:
    Students:
      value:
        - name: James Bond
          teacher: 
            $ref: '#/components/examples/teacherTrunchbull'
          postalAddress:
            $ref: '#/components/examples/london'
        - name: Bilbo Baggins
          teacher: 
            $ref: '#/components/examples/teacherTrunchbull'
          postalAddress:
            $ref: '#/components/examples/london'
        -  .......
...
components:
  examples:
    teacherTrunchbull:
      (value: ??)
        name: Agatha Trunchbull
        address: School street 34
        postalAddress:
          number: 5201
          name: London 
    london:
      (value: ??)
        number: 5201
        name: London
```

For the record, I do know that examples needs to contain "value" as field, but all I can manage to do with it is to create a full example, not sub-components for my examples.

I do suspect that OpenAPI version 3.0.1. does not support what I am asking about, in which case, only this works:

```
...
  examples:
    Students:
      $ref: '#/components/examples/students'
```

If this is the case, please confirm it so that we can call it case closed.
But if what I am asking about does exist, how then do I do it?

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `example` does not support using `$ref` in this manner.

From [this](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1986#issuecomment-519988505) bug thread:

> What we meant here (and if needed, can clarify further) is that the
> value given here is the actual value of the example. It is not to be
> further parsed by tooling. So documentation or mocking services should
> not try to parse the $ref's before further 'using' them.
>
> The reason behind is exactly $ref's. We can't distinguish when the end
> user would want to use $ref as a resolved reference and when they'd
> want to use it as a literal value (which is a very valid case). As
> such, we decided that the examples would be non-parsed literal values.
> At the moment, there's no way to have parsable examples, as external
> examples are literal values as well.